# Merging projected graphs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use node [similarity](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/similarity/) algorithms from GDS to compute the similarities with two different criteria (one with knn and the other with structural similarity).
Now I end up with two projected graphs, says A and B. These two graphs have the same node set, but the edge types are different.
I want to merge two graphs into one, i.e., by allowing two edges between two nodes before exporting the merged graph to a database.
How can I do it in cypher?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question you have two different subgraphs `subA` and `subB` based on KNN and some structural similarity and you now want to save those similarities to the DB as relationships between nodes?

If so then you can use the `write` methods of either subgraph as described [here for KNN](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/knn/#algorithms-knn-examples-write).